# Clojure app running only in tcp6

Tags: websocket, clojure, webserver

So I'm in over my head, but I nearly have a working Clojure app with WebSocket connection deployed to a prod-like environment, but there are a few things that I can't seem to work out. When I hit the endpoint with `curl` from `localhost` I get the response I was hoping for, so far so good. But when I try access it from my domain, I don't get a connection. When I checked `netstat` to make sure the port (`8001`) is open, I see the following:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3283/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3218/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3283/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 :::8001                 :::*                    LISTEN      3260/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3283/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      3218/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      3283/nginx: master
```

I am running `ufw` but I already `allow`ed the port, so I'm not sure if there is something I need to do when running the app to make it available as a normal `tcp` service? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Here is the command that is currently running:

```
java -jar test.jar 8001
```

Also I was torn between here and serverfault, but opted for stackoverflow because I think it's Clojure-centric. Please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have a good setup where nginx is providing a reverse proxy to your app, this is a solid way to go about it. 
A tcp6 listener on :::8001 is likely also listening on ipv4 as well as ipv6 it just doesn't print both of them
At lest at a first glance it looks like nginx is missing a forward rule for `/*` to `localhost:8001/*`

they look something like this in ngins.conf

```
location ~ ^/.* {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $fwd_proto;
  proxy_redirect off;

  proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure I have something set up incorrectly in nginx then. I would like to keep the rest of my web sites in place, but add the config necessary to point requests to `wss://domain.com:8001` to the endpoint. I opened another question, hopefully it is what I need.